# Color SVG Sprites

Tags: css, sprite

I've been using icon-fonts created at IcoMoon and they are fantastic. For this I import an SVG Illistrator output (or use premade icons) and create font files that are attached using CSS @Font-Face. These are only ever one color.

I've been reading about SVG Sprites like here: http://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/

I've tried uploading illistrator SVG files with different colors into IcoMoon (as explained at the bottom of the link above) and then creating a SVG Sprite but the color never comes through (always just one color).

Am I doing something wrong with IcoMoon? How can I create a color SVG Sprite using a site like IcoMoon that can be used to display icons where required?

thankyou

Note: i need multiple colors in each image. (not just one color styled via CSS).

Comment: Icon fonts can be styled with CSS on the page.

Comment: yes I needed mutiple color (should have explained that better) - ok I will try out what you have mentioned - thankyou

Comment: You can't have multiple colors in an icon font for the reason I mentioned earlier. If you want to use multiple colors in a single sprite include it alone instead of embedding it in a font.

Comment: by chance is there any sites that combine multi-color images into a Sprite - eg: multiple SVGs.

Comment: Why not layer the SVGs ontop of one another and had a `fill:color` css attribute to them?